# Gravitational force due to asymmetric Earth shell

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

According to above link the gravitational force inside a symmetrical shell due to itself is zero.

Is it also true for an asymmetrical shell?

Comment: Just a hint for reading this kind of thing: they wouldn't have put the qualifier (symmetric) in there if it didn't matter *somehow*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily convince yourself that this is not true. Just imagine a test particle on one side of a spherical shell. If the density is uniform, the theorem will apply. Now, however, decrease the density of that half of the shell until it's 0. Obviously this other half would attract the test particle.

Alternatively, if changing density is not an option and you can only change the shape, then alter the shape of one half of the sphere following a fractal pattern until it becomes the overwhelmingly dominant contribution to the mass. The same reasoning then applies.

Comment: Afaik he didn't mentioned the possibility of a density change, the whole shell theorem is about infinitesimal width, constant density shells.

Comment: He didn't really specify what he was asking for. It's not really clear what sort of asymmetry we're allowed to introduce. Either way, like I said, if all you can change is the shape you can always use some sort of fractal pattern to effectively achieve the equivalent of any arbitrary density you want.

Answer (score -1):

The first half of this theorem is: you can substitute the total mass in the centre to get the net gravity. It probably don't stays, although it needs a little bit of integration.

The second (there is no net gravity inside the shell), I think it passes, if the shell is convex. The proof is exactly the same as you can see in the wiki page.

Comment: If you change the shape in question there is absolutely no reason to think you will achieve the same result when integrating. The whole derivation is based off the fact that the shell is spherical.

Comment: @ticster Then get a paper and start to integrate this for yourself.